My React website works as intendet on the developement server but not on the real website - where do I have to look for the reason?
I want to embed a datawrapper map like this:
import InnerHTML from 'dangerously-set-html-content'
export function Map1(){
    const htmlFile = `<div style="min-height: 374px">
        <script type="text/javascript" defer src="src/utils/mapscript.js" charset="utf-8">
        </script>
        <noscript>
        <img src="https://static.igem.wiki/teams/5247/charts-maps/map1-full.png" alt="" />
        </noscript>
</div>`
return(
    <InnerHTML html={htmlFile} />
)   
}

and it works perfectly fine on the development server, displays everything.
But on the website itself, it does not display. Not even the image specified in the "noscript" part.
In the console of the webpage it says for the mapscript.js file:

Uncaught SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'

But the file starts like
"!function(){"use strict";const t=new Set(["0","false","null"]),e={allowEditing:Boolean,dark:function" so I have no idea where the "<" supposedly comes from.
The pipeline on GitLab for the website passed.
Let me know what further information is needed for the description.
To try and solve it I used different versions:
export function Map2(){
    const htmlFile = `<div style="min-height: 374px">
        <script type="text/javascript" defer src="src/utils/mapscript.js" charset="utf-8">
        </script>
        <noscript>
        <img src="https://static.igem.wiki/teams/5247/charts-maps/map1-full.png" alt="" />
        </noscript>
</div>`
return(
    <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: htmlFile }} />
)   
}

import DOMPurify from 'dompurify';
export function Map1(){
    const htmlFile = `<div style="min-height: 374px">
        <script type="text/javascript" defer src="src/utils/mapscript.js" charset="utf-8">
        </script>
        <noscript>
        <img src="https://static.igem.wiki/teams/5247/charts-maps/map1-full.png" alt="" />
        </noscript>
</div>`
const sanitizedHTML = DOMPurify.sanitize(htmlFile);
return(
    <InnerHTML html={htmlFile} />
)   
}

export function Map3(){
    return(
        <div style={{minHeight: "374px"}}>
        <script type="text/javascript" defer src="src/utils/mapscript.js" charet="utf-8">
        </script>
        <noscript>
        <img src="https://static.igem.wiki/teams/5247/charts-maps/map1-full.png" alt="" />
        </noscript>
</div>
    )
}

But they did not work on the  website or on the development server, so i discarded them.

What can you see in your browser's console when nothing works?

@AKX Oh damn it I di not look there... thanks you.
I have no idea why it says there is a syntax error, but that is a clue.
Uncaught SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<' in mapscript.js:1:1

Then I'd guess you're getting a 404 for mapscript.js (and the 404 page is HTML). Getting a 404 would make sense since a bundled site won't have a src/...

@AKX I am new to this so this does not make sense to me, could you recommend me a resource to learn more about bundling so I can understand how to fix it?

Your easiest fix is to put that script in static/ (or assets/ or whatever your bundler calls it) and refer to it with that URL.

Unfortunately, my project does not have an assets folder.
I did not create it, but got it from the institution I am doing this for. They have some lines in the .gitlab-ci.yml file to create the public folder, if i understood it correctly.
But that is another topic altogether, you solved my question, thank you.

@AKX solved my question:
The mapscript.js file is not in the public folder of my project and that's why it is giving error not found.
Now I have to figure out how to get that into the public folder so the error should go away.

Oh yeah, public/ is one more option. Good luck!

You just try to added the 'default' keyword in the function, like below
export default function Map2(){
    const htmlFile = `<div style="min-height: 374px">
        <script type="text/javascript" defer src="src/utils/mapscript.js" charset="utf-8">
        </script>
        <noscript>
        <img src="https://static.igem.wiki/teams/5247/charts-maps/map1-full.png" alt="" />
        </noscript>
</div>`
return(
    <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: htmlFile }} />
)   
}

refer this document importing and exporting components

This does not solve it, but thank you.
It indeed seems to be a problem with the mapscript.js and its location.

Good, it's related to mapscript.js and locations issues. @AKX Thanks
